# Get current user ID in Confide laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How to get the current logged-in user's details in Laravel 4? My code is:

```
$user = User::find(Confide::user()->id);

$message = new Message(Input::all());
$message->user_id = $user; 
$message->save();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Laravel default Authentication so you can simply call like the following

```
$id = Auth::id();
```

Laravel documentation explain like the following

> To retrieve the authenticated user's ID, you may use the `id` method:
>
> $id = Auth::id();

Read more about Authentication at Laravel's Documentation.

Comment: IM using confide authentication

Comment: Confide uses `Auth` so it should still work.  If you just want the `user` model though, simply use `$user = Auth::user()`.  No need to try and find the id of the user who is already logged in to search the database.